Enabling gso udp in nginx results in bad length udp packets from tcpdump
I have compiled the latest version of Nginx with H3/QUIC support and everything is working fine.
However, after enabling quic_gso on, tcpdump is now flooded with "bad length" datagrams:
14:47:10.639253 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.https > XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.41686: UDP, bad length 8490 > 1415
14:47:10.639264 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.https > XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.53144: UDP, bad length 17368 > 1336
14:47:10.639268 IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.https > XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX.22040: UDP, bad length 22950 > 1350

It appears that Nginx is now properly sending larger udp packets, but they are not being segmented properly by the kernel or NIC.
The test machine is running Rocky Linux 9.3 with the latest kernel version 6.6.30 and a Mellanox ConnectX-5 Ex 100G NIC.
GSO is enabled on the Mellanox card:
# ethtool -k ens1f1np1
Features for ens1f1np1:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
        tx-checksum-ipv4: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-ip-generic: on
        tx-checksum-ipv6: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-sctp: off [fixed]
scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
        tx-tcp-segmentation: on
        tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
        tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation: off
        tx-tcp6-segmentation: on
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off
rx-vlan-offload: on
tx-vlan-offload: on
ntuple-filters: off
receive-hashing: on
highdma: on [fixed]
rx-vlan-filter: on
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: on
tx-gre-csum-segmentation: on
tx-ipxip4-segmentation: on
tx-ipxip6-segmentation: on
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: on
tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation: on
tx-gso-partial: on
tx-tunnel-remcsum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-sctp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-esp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-udp-segmentation: on
tx-gso-list: off [fixed]
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]
tx-nocache-copy: off
loopback: off [fixed]
rx-fcs: off
rx-all: off
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: on
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-filter: on [fixed]
l2-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hw-tc-offload: on
esp-hw-offload: off [fixed]
esp-tx-csum-hw-offload: off [fixed]
rx-udp_tunnel-port-offload: on
tls-hw-tx-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-rx-offload: off [fixed]
rx-gro-hw: off [fixed]
tls-hw-record: off [fixed]
rx-gro-list: off
macsec-hw-offload: on
rx-udp-gro-forwarding: off
hsr-tag-ins-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-tag-rm-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-dup-offload: off [fixed]

What am I missing?
EDIT:
I got another test machine. Exactly the same RL9.3, kernel and software.
Only difference is Intel 10G card (Intel Corporation 82599ES 10-Gigabit SFI/SFP+ Network Connection):
# ethtool -k ens8f0
Features for ens8f0:
rx-checksumming: on
tx-checksumming: on
        tx-checksum-ipv4: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-ip-generic: on
        tx-checksum-ipv6: off [fixed]
        tx-checksum-fcoe-crc: on [fixed]
        tx-checksum-sctp: on
scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather: on
        tx-scatter-gather-fraglist: off [fixed]
tcp-segmentation-offload: on
        tx-tcp-segmentation: on
        tx-tcp-ecn-segmentation: off [fixed]
        tx-tcp-mangleid-segmentation: off
        tx-tcp6-segmentation: on
generic-segmentation-offload: on
generic-receive-offload: on
large-receive-offload: off
rx-vlan-offload: on
tx-vlan-offload: on
ntuple-filters: off
receive-hashing: on
highdma: on [fixed]
rx-vlan-filter: on
vlan-challenged: off [fixed]
tx-lockless: off [fixed]
netns-local: off [fixed]
tx-gso-robust: off [fixed]
tx-fcoe-segmentation: on [fixed]
tx-gre-segmentation: on
tx-gre-csum-segmentation: on
tx-ipxip4-segmentation: on
tx-ipxip6-segmentation: on
tx-udp_tnl-segmentation: on
tx-udp_tnl-csum-segmentation: on
tx-gso-partial: on
tx-tunnel-remcsum-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-sctp-segmentation: off [fixed]
tx-esp-segmentation: on
tx-udp-segmentation: on
tx-gso-list: off [fixed]
fcoe-mtu: off [fixed]
tx-nocache-copy: off
loopback: off [fixed]
rx-fcs: off [fixed]
rx-all: off
tx-vlan-stag-hw-insert: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-hw-parse: off [fixed]
rx-vlan-stag-filter: off [fixed]
l2-fwd-offload: off
hw-tc-offload: off
esp-hw-offload: on
esp-tx-csum-hw-offload: on
rx-udp_tunnel-port-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-tx-offload: off [fixed]
tls-hw-rx-offload: off [fixed]
rx-gro-hw: off [fixed]
tls-hw-record: off [fixed]
rx-gro-list: off
macsec-hw-offload: off [fixed]
rx-udp-gro-forwarding: off
hsr-tag-ins-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-tag-rm-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-fwd-offload: off [fixed]
hsr-dup-offload: off [fixed]


and now the same tcpdump show perfectly fine TCP packets with size >1500:
17:35:31.878697 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.56044: UDP, length 14380
17:35:31.878775 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.55512: UDP, length 4131
17:35:31.879076 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.https > xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.60301: UDP, length 10304

So why for mellanox card with the same OS/nginx/software configuration tcpdump show bad length?
